# How can I Create APK file from HTML, CSS, Js and Python files?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, apk

I am a beginner to programming and after learning python I want to make apps and so, I tried another way I.e. using python, HTML, CSS and Js to create my app and I have done so using eel module in python but, to publish it on Play Store I need to convert it into APK file and also needed some signed version, certificate etc. so, *I have a folder which contains My Files (.py, .html, .css, .js and some txt and img)* how Can I this whole folder into **1 APK** file?

Comment: Yes, you can include arbitrary files in an APK.  Have you looked at the tutorials?  There are several ways to convert a Python app into an APK.

Comment: No I haven't looked at any tutorial if possible could you please share link. @Tim Roberts

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create an `APK` file, that is an application for android, then there are two ways. One is

## Using [Kivy](https://kivy.org)

> Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
> that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.

You can use kivy to create android apps with python, but **You cannot use HTML, CSS AND JAVASCRIPT**.

##### `Note`: You need `Linux` to debug your kivy app into `.apk` file.

---

## Using [Reactjs](https://reactjs.org)

> A JavaScript library for building user interfaces.Design simple views for each state in your application, and React will efficiently update and render just the right components when your data changes.

*React* is a popular javascript framework which was developed by facebook. You can use that to create android application **with HTML, CSS AND JAVASCRIPT** but **WITHOUT PYTHON**.

---

Apart from this, there can be many other ways which you can use.